# getting cors issue when hitting request to grails

Tags: java, angular, grails, cors

Iam getting this issue

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/v1/store/getstore' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

My config in application.yaml is

```
grails:
cors:
    enabled: true
    allowedOrigins:
    - http://localhost:4200
```

and in url mapping

```
"/v1/store/getStore"(controller: 'store', action: 'getStore')
```

when i directly hit request as "http://localhost:8082/store/getstore" its not throwing error but after placing in urlMapping its throwing cors issue.

Comment: That error message indicates the server is responding to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request with a 3xx redirect. The preflight fails unless the response is a 2xx success message. So you need to figure out why the server is responding to the OPTIONS request and what URL it’s trying to redirect to and why — and then either reconfigure the server do prevent that redirect or else change your frontend JavaScript code to make the request to the redirect URL instead.

Comment: actually server is responding with 200 for first OPTION request but again OPTION request is being hit by angular.

Answer (score 0):

create proxy.conf.json file at root folder and edit the below:

```
{
    "/": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8082/",
      "secure": false
    }
  }
```

change the package json command for start:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --open",
```

use the URL mapping as same `"/v1/store/getStore"(controller: 'store', action: 'getStore')`